# How to make vue js website printer accessible?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I have a website build with vue js and I used a lot of scooped styling for different components.

In many websites separate css files are provides with media="print" to facilitate print version.

How do I achieve this in my vue is app/website?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a link tag inside your HTML which links to the print stylesheet, you can then let your browser know through the media attribute that it serves for printing only:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print">`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp